# Multiplying three factorials with three binomials in polynomial identity

Tags: combinatorial-identities

I have checked the following identity (1) below for $n\leq 40$ with a computer.
Let $(n)_k$ denote the falling factorial $n(n-1)\ldots (n-k+1)$, let
$Z_n=\sum_{k=0}^n (n)_k x^{n-k}$, and finally let
$D_n=x^2Z_{n-1}Z_{n-2}-2nxZ_nZ_{n-2}+Z_nZ_{n-1}$. Then, I conjecture that

$$
D_n=\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n-2}
(n-j)!(n-j-1)!(j-i)! 
\binom{n-2}{j}\binom{j}{i}\binom{2n+1-i-j}{j-i}x^{i+j}\tag{1}
$$

I tried my usual tools (induction, WS method, using similar identities) and failed. Any help appreciated.

Question also asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211688/multiplying-three-factorials-with-three-binomials-in-polynomial-identity)

Comment: Did you try to find coefficients of $D_n$ in http://oeis.org/ ?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Which coefficients ? $D_n$ is a sum on two indexes $i$ and $j$, and the summand involves extra parameters $n$ and $x$ in addition to $i$ and $j$.

Comment: You have just a sequence of polynomials: $D_2=2$, $D_3=2(6+6x+x^2)$,... And they have coefficients 2, 2, 12, 12, ... I've checked. The answer is "no".

Comment: But this triangle of numbers is good enough. At least first columns and dioganals are simple.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Every column, row and diagonal is a polynomial.